# Collection is readonly on array in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class FruitBoxViewModel {

    public FruitBoxViewModel()
    {
        BoxLabels = new BoxLabelViewModel[3];
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BoxLabelViewModel[] BoxLabels {get; set; }
}
```

A commented requested to see what the `BoxLabelViewModel` looks like, here it is:

```
public class BoxLabelViewModel {
    public string SkuCode {get; set;}
    public int? ProductionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Each `FruitBox` can have between 1 and 3 `BoxLabels`, no more, no less. To enforce, this, I thought I'd use an `Array` instead of a `List`.

I have a for loop in my Razor view that handles my inputs on the page:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
  @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.BoxLabels[i].SkuCode)
  @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.BoxLabels[i].SkuCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}
```

When I submit the form, I get the yellow screen of death (YSOD) with the error:

> **Collection is read-only.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.

Is there a rule I don't know about that says you should never use an Array in your ViewModels or something?

Comment: What are definitions of `BoxLabel` and `BoxLabelViewModel`?

Comment: One was a typo that I've fixed, and I've now added code for `BoxLabelViewModel`

Comment: One optimization suggestion. Use `Model.Boxlabels.Length` (or `Count`) for `for` statement instead of fixed number 3, so you don't have to edit number at two places if you choose to modify item count.

Comment: you're right, I only put 3 cause I was going crazy and thought the count function might be the culprit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the 'got you' cases of using array instead of list. Model binder will not create new instance of an array because you have provided one in constructor. Then it will use it as `IList` instance and try to invoke `Insert` or `Add` and such calls will fail for array and succeed for list.

Just remove the assignment form constructor or use list in your model and write some JS to validate your form before sending post request. Then validate count of items on server side.

Comment: This is not correct. The `DefaultModelBinder` will bind to an array just fine. The real issue is the constructor which sets `BoxLabels = new BoxLabelViewModel[3];` - creating a read-only collection. Just remove that line and the model will be correctly bound (having said that, using `IList<T>` is preferred because it allows you to add 3 elements and use `for(int i = 0; i < Model.BoxLabels.Count; i++) { ...`

Comment: Why life is so java...